# Character encoding and using Zend\Dom\Query

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8, zend-framework2

I have a problem with the encoding of polish characters using Zend Framework 2. I use:

```
use Zend\Dom\Query;
```

Rest code:

```
$dom = new Query(); 
$document = '<ul id="test"><li>ęółąśłżźć</li><li>test</li></ul>';
$dom->setDocumentHtml($document);
$dom->setEncoding('utf-8');
$ul = $dom->execute('#test li');
foreach($ul as $li)
{
    echo $li->nodeValue;
}
```

Result:

```
ÄÃ³ÅÄÅÅÅ¼ÅºÄtest
```

[image]

How to display correctly these characters?

I tried to use PHP functions (iconv, utf8_encode) but without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the hood Zend\Dom\Query uses [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) which is built on libxml, whose HTML parser was made for HTML 4. The default encoding for which is ISO-8859-1.

`Query::setEncoding()` doesn't influence how a document is loaded.

---

#### Workarounds:

First use [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to translate anything above the ASCII range into its html entity equivalent.

```
$dom->setDocumentHtml(mb_convert_encoding($document, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

Or hack in a meta tag or xml declaration specifying UTF-8.

```
$dom->setDocumentHtml('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=utf-8" />' . $document);
```

```
$dom->setDocumentHtml('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $document);
```

Comment: Thank you, you save me several hours.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts managed to work around the problem, but I think it is not a good solution.

I've added the appropriate headers into an HTML document

```
$document = '<!DOCTYPE html>'. //Add
'<html lang="pl">'. //Add
'<head>'. //Add
    '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />'. //Add
    '<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pl" />'. //Add
'</head>'. //Add
'<body>'. //Add
    '<ul id="test">'.
        '<li>ęółąśłżźć</li>'.
        '<li>test</li>'.
    '</ul>'.
'</body>'. //Add
'</html>'; //Add
```

The result is good